# Modify a string to remove characters

Tags: string, delete

I have a text file where the barcode is in column 18. I'm interested in removing the last 16 characters from a TCGA barcode for a long list of samples or alternatively I want to print only the first 12 characters in the string from column 18 to a new column. 
The characters differ in each line of the file so I can not simply use the sed command to remove characters following a certain character.

For example: TCGA-2E-A9G8-01A-11D-A403-09 needs to be shorted to TCGA-2E-A9G8 and print the shorted ID in a new column

I've seen responses such as: echo "${string:0:-16}" I'm very new to programing so i'm not sure how to automate this for a spreadsheet with over 300,000 lines and directed to a specific column

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{print substr($18,1,12)}' input
```

This will print characters 1-12 of column 18.  This assumes that your text file is separated by whitespace. Which it likely isn't.

For CSV:

```
awk -F, '{print substr($18,1,12)}' input
```

Based on Steeldriver's comment for adding this output to a new column:

```
awk '{$(NF+1) = substr($18,1,12)} 1' input > output
```

Unfortunately this creates a new file.  `gawk` can modify a file in place but your best bet is to create a new file and then remove the old file.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to print the trimmed down ID in a new column within the original file?

Comment: I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.  When i do                                       awk '{print substr($18,1,12)}' input>output  i'm getting it to print the from the 12 to last column.  Not the first 12 characters in column 18.

Comment: Getting it to print the what?

Comment: its returning data from the 12 to last column

Comment: @Meghan if it's not working for you, then please edit your question to include a minimal representative example of your input file

Comment: Here is a copy of the first line of my file, not i've modified so now i'm interested in column $16.Hugo_Symbol Entrez_Gene_Id Center NCBI_Build Chromosome Start_position End_position Strand Variant_Classification Variant_Type Reference_Allele Tumor_Seq_Allele1 Tumor_Seq_Allele2 dbSNP_RS dbSNP_Val_Status Tumor_Sample_Barcode
AF121898.3 0 broad.mit.edu 37 8 88613386 88613386 + RNA DEL T T -   TCGA-2E-A9G8-01A-11D-A403-09

Comment: Please add the sample data as an edit to your question in a code block so that it's legible.